# How can I get the url of a thread from my bot

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger-bot

I am developping a bot for a facebook page. However in some case I would like to send a message to the communuty manager to answer directly to the user.
But I can find a way to get the url of the conversation
The format should be something like https://www.facebook.com/{PAGE_ID}/messages/?threadid={THREAD_ID}

The typical message that I get from messenger is:

```
{'entry': [{'time': 1480427999710, 'messaging': [{'sender': {'id': '1460044464009882'}, 'recipient': {'id': '1171951382925000'}, 'postback': {'payload': 'BUTTON_CONTACT_US'}, 'timestamp': 1480427999710}], 'id': '1171951382925000'}], 'object': 'page'}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Ok so someone from the facebook answered me.

> We don't expose that information. In the context of Messenger
>   platform, contact with the recipient should only be done using the
>   Send API using the ID's we send you via Webhooks.

It's quite annoying when people are interacting a lot with the bot but you don't have a dedicated back-end to handle all the conversation (as a CM)

Comment: that sucks! I wanted to build a help system where a live person can jump into the conversation from the page from a link, but no love. Will have to lookup manually from the page or roll an interface between them. Thanks for posting the response though.

Comment: I am also looking for a similar solution